# How to post data to a Webservice using JSON?

Tags: android, json

I have to send the following data to webservice at URl

The format of data to be send is:

```
new_member=[{"email":"himanshu@avigma.com","username":"himanshu01","pwd":"himanshu01"}]
```

where `email`,`username` and `pwd` is the key and has corresponding value string fetched through edittext string. I am posting this data on click of button.

I am not getting any response bcoz i have tried to counter check this with my co developer in his iphone same app iphone version as the username and password is not valid is said by server.

My `Signup.java` class is:

```
    Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        EditText e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String a=e.getText().toString();
        EditText e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String b=e1.getText().toString();
        EditText e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String c=e2.getText().toString();
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit 
                HttpResponse response; 
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); 
                try{ 
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("URL"); 
                    //System.out.println(post);
                    json.put("email", a);
                    json.put("username", b);
                    json.put("pwd",c); 
                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity( "JSON: " + json.toString());   
                    se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")); 
                    post.setEntity(se); 
                    response = client.execute(post); 
                    /*Checking response */ 
                    if(response!=null){ 
                        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity 
 //System.out.println(response);
                }
                }
                catch(Exception e){ 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                    //createDialog("Error", "Cannot Estabilish Connection"); 
                } 
        }

    }
            );
```

Please assist me i am a newbie in JSON and parsing in Android.Thanx.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

here is the example

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
    "https://api.dailymile.com/entries.json?oauth_token="
    + token);

httpPost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

data.put("message", dailyMilePost.getMessage());
JSONObject workoutData = new JSONObject();
data.put("workout", workoutData);
workoutData.put("activity_type", dailyMilePost.getActivityType());
workoutData.put("completed_at", dailyMilePost.getCompletedAt());
JSONObject distanceData = new JSONObject();
workoutData.put("distance", distanceData);
distanceData.put("value", dailyMilePost.getDistanceValue());
distanceData.put("units", dailyMilePost.getDistanceUnits());
workoutData.put("duration", dailyMilePost.getDurationInSeconds());
workoutData.put("title", dailyMilePost.getTitle());
workoutData.put("felt", dailyMilePost.getFelt());

StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(data.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

see the complete information from this blog http://simpleprogrammer.com/2011/06/04/oauth-and-rest-in-android-part-2/

Comment: Thanx for the reply please tell me how i pass new_member= as i am appending in the url but the actual provided url is http://www.fourerr.com/ws/signup Should i take newmember as json object.?? Please assist me..

Comment: what this new_member value? try to pass like token was pass in example

Comment: I would recommend using not **StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(data.toString());** but **StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(paramInput.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);** - In my case this solved the problem with encoding cyrillic characters in json-string.

Comment: for encoding it's required HTTP.UTF_8

Answer (score 4):

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "himanshu@avigma.com"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "himanshu01")); 
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pwd", "himanshu01")); 

// You have to add your parameters as nameValuePairs

String res  = "";
                try
                {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("URL");  

                             // Add your data  

                             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  
                             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);  
                             res = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                             JSONTokener t = new JSONTokener(res);
                             JSONArray a = new JSONArray(t);
                             JSONObject o = a.getJSONObject(0);
                             String sc = o.getString("success");
                             if(sc.equals("1"))
                             {
                                 // posted successfully
                             }
else
{
 // error occurred
}
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Dont forgot to specify **android.permission.INTERNET** permission

Answer (score 2):

The block parentheses denote a JSON array, so you just need to wrap your json object in a JSONArray.

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("email", a);
json.put("username", b);
json.put("pwd",c); 
array.put(json);
```

The put `array` into entity.

Important: you should not perform long-running (e.g. network) tasks on main thread. Use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to properly perform long-running tasks in the background and then update UI.

Comment: Thanx for the reply please tell me how i pass new_member= as i am appending in the url but the actual provided url is http://www.fourerr.com/ws/signup Should i take newmember as json object.?? Please assist me..

Answer (score 1):

First of all you'll need to put the `code` that gets the `Strings` from the `EditTexts` inside the `onClick()` method.

Then it looks like the server expects a `JSONArray` with just one item, so you'll need to create a JSONArray, something like this :

```
JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put(json); //your current json
StringEntity entity=new StringEntity("new_member="+jsonArray);
```