# java.lang.IllegalStateException when sending JSON to webservice using HttpResponse

Tags: android, json, web-services, httpclient, httpresponse

I'm trying to pass a JSON data object to a webservice in my Android Application. I've a button and when i click on it I want to send the location to my webservice. Everything works fine untill the last command. I've got my code from another post here : 
[How to post data to a Webservice using JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520011/how-to-post-data-to-a-webservice-using-json)

It should be work so I think the problem is somewhere else but the error says nothing to me.. this is my function that runs on onclick:

```
public void clickbuttonRecieve(View v) {
         new MyAsync().execute();
 }


 private class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... tmps) {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://bomatec.be/webservice2.php");

            httpPost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            try {
                String message;

                data.put("user", "12");
                data.put("lat", "50.8");
                data.put("lng", "4.3");


            }catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
            }

            try {
                StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(data.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
                httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            }catch(java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e){
                Log.e("MYAPP", "UnsupportedEncodingException JSON exception", e);
            }


            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e("MYAPP", "IOException", e);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Error stack :

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
                                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
                                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
                                                                                                    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
                                                                                                    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
                                                                                                    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
                                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
                                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
                                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
                                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
                                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
                                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
                                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
                                                                                                    at com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven.MainActivity$MyAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:177)
                                                                                                    at com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven.MainActivity$MyAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:148)
                                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
                                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 
                                                                                                 Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
                                                                                                    at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
                                                                                                    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
                                                                                                    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236) 
                                                                                                    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214) 
                                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137) 
                                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164) 
                                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119) 
                                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360) 
                                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555) 
                                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487) 
                                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465) 
                                                                                                    at com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven.MainActivity$MyAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:177) 
                                                                                                    at com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven.MainActivity$MyAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:148) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305) 
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
                                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 
                                                                                                 Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
                                                                                                    at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method) 
                                                                                                    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55) 
                                                                                                    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405) 
                                                                                                    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236) 
                                                                                                    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214) 
                                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137) 
                                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164) 
                                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119) 
                                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360) 
                                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555) 
                                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487) 
                                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465) 
                                                                                                    at com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven.MainActivity$MyAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:177) 
                                                                                                    at com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven.MainActivity$MyAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:148) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305) 
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
                                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: You should use your code with AsyncTask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150637/networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have NetworkOnMainThreadException exception, you must put your onClick code into AsyncTask. Android prohibits network operations on UI thread, this is to prevent blocking main UI message queue.

Example code is:

```
 private class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... tmps) {
         // do your work here!!
         return null;
     }
 }
```

in your onclick - execute: `new MyAsync().execute()`

Comment: I have no knowledge of AsyncTask. Is it 'total' different?

Comment: @user5488652 read docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I changed my code. Still get same error, you can see my code at original question. Thanks for your help

Comment: @user5488652 you should learn to read LogCat - you need to add permission to access internet - `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)` Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to your manifest.

Comment: Also - HttpClient was depracated, you should use Url

Comment: Thx for your help! It works now. I've got one more question. The AsyncTask keeps running, do you know why he does that?

Comment: That's just the task of an AsyncTask I assume

Comment: AsyncTask is based on thread pool, so if you ask why its thread still exists after AsyncTask finished - then its because it will get reused for next AsyncTask.